# Laptop repurpose - questions about safety and conversion cables

Tags: laptop

I am trying to rehouse an old laptop because the plastic case has fallen apart. I want to turn it into a desktop pc, with perhaps an aluminum or acrylic case, and repurpose the monitor as a stand-alone monitor. I have already broken down the laptop and labeled each of its components.

I had a few questions regarding this:

- I am not a hardware professional. When working with the device, possibly trouble-shooting it outside of the case, are any components of the board  dangerous to touch?
- Do I need latex gloves or a grounding bracelet?
- What types of conversion plugs/cords might I need to buy? Would this information be
  in the computer hardware manual?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not a hardware professional, I would reccommend NOT doing this, because laptops are so hard to work with. You can repurpose the laptop as a desktop by plugging in an external keyboard and mouse and monitor, thats how I did it when the screen of one of my laptops started bugging.

Having said that, you can do that, but dont expect to find much information in the manual or on the internet. You don't need gloves, but a grounding bracelet can be useful. Also you need a chassis with chassis detechtion, or fake chassis detechtion, because most laptops need that (too bad :( ). I guess the laptop screen cannot be reused easily using hdmi/DP, because there are no converters for those connectors, but if the cable is long enough, you can just reconnect that to the motherboard. The sides of the boards are always safe to touch, but it is really hard to kill the hardware if you don't (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXkgbmr3dRA, not so headphone user friendly).

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful feedback. I was using the device as you described for a while. Unfortunately, the cracking in the plastic case runs right along the power button. Therefore, any time the screen shakes or is moved, it puts pressure on the button and shuts of the machine. I pulled the plastic button out and it helped a bit but the issue persisted. Then the battery that I had replaced stopped registering or something, and the device only works when plugged in. At this point, I sort of figured a new house might make everything easier and more accessible.

Comment: I watched some videos which suggested I only needed a controller board with hdmi input to use the screen. I ordered this one from Ali express (https://www.aliexpress.com/i/4000012243147.html) and am hoping for the best

Comment: From videos, I had thought primarily I would need some kind of power button converter to short the two pins where the keyboard connects to the motherboard. I hadn't thought about the chassis detection.

Comment: The video link you posted was funny and informative. Thank you!